# Expired SSL certificate on mailserver

Tags: ssl-certificate, email-server

As daft as it sounds, I've let an SSL certificate expire -- or it will within the next 12 hours.

My only real concern with this is a mailserver, which is configured to listen for encrypted (port 465/995) and non-encrypted connections (port 25).

What will happen when the cert expires? Will incoming SSL traffic try 25 after 465 fails?

---

As an addendum, I decided to close 465 for the duration (about 24 hours) and I don't believe anything was lost; stuff that would have normally come secure got delivered on port 25.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends.

### EDIT 1

(Because my first answer was snarky and bad)

This is entirely dependent on all sending servers' preferences. If the sending server that connects to your server is set to...

- ...first connect with TLS over port 465 but die on an expired certificate, then yes you're toast.
- ...first connect with TLS over port 465 but be okay with an expired certificate, then you're fine.
- ...first connect with TLS over port 465, notice an expired certificate and then check for an unencrypted SMTP port, then you're fine.

There are probably a few other branches on that flow chart that I'm not listing out. The outcome of this scenario is entirely out of your hands. Go get your cert updated pronto. =)

Comment: Just what I was afraid of...

Comment: @goldilocks Okay, okay. I gave a real answer now. :D

Comment: +1 for snarkyness, would +1 again for professionalism (removing said snarkyness)